# RAM detection issue

Tags: windows-7, memory, bios, hardware-detection

Is there a way to trigger RAM detection without removing it from the slot and putting it again?

The thing is I bought a new RAM and it works fine, but every time I shut down (sometimes hibernate) my computer, it goes undetected, and to make it work, I have to remove it from the slot, turn on my computer, turn it off, then plug the Ram and turn on computer again.

Device Spec: Dell Inspiron 1545 (Laptop)

Ram specs: DDR2 PC2-6400 • 1.8V, manufacturer: HIGHLEVEL

Comment: this almost has to be power management related. Is the stick of the same voltage as you other sticks?

Comment: yes, it is, I was sure about this when I bought the RAM

Comment: Do you have other slots you could use and troubleshoot with?  Try swapping to one of the other slots and see if you can replicate the problem.

Comment: I will do that (y)

Comment: To analyze the problem. it would help for you to specify in the post your exact computer model, motherboard, RAM sticks and their actual slots.

Comment: Isn't that a job for memtest86+?

Comment: After reading this: `Is there a way to trigger RAM detection without removing it from the slot and putting it again?` i say `NO` unless you want to be electrocuted...

Answer (score 3):

I would advise you to update to the last BIOS. This looks like a small bios bug.

Another thing you can do is switching the DIMM's spots (DIMM 1 to slot 2 and vise-versa). Sometimes the BIOS doesn't properly detect the timings and frequencies (goes for the freq/times of one DIMM and ignore the other) when they are not identical.

If your bios is sort of unrestricted (but usually not the case in laptops), you can verify if the frequencies/timings are okey (via CPU-Z in windows which allows you to see the defined parameters in SPD's) and modify them properly in BIOS (by setting them manually).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how old this computer is, but first I would recommend you update your bios to the latest version.

Next try this: If the computer is a desktop, unplug it from power, then after a few minutes plug it back in. If the computer is a laptop, remove the battery first. Does that work?

Another idea: Most computers have a BIOS setting that says something like quick POST (Power On Self Test) or FULL POST. Select FULL post, this may redetect your ram on every boot.

Note: Even if these things work for you, you should run a program like memtest86 to verify that your memory is indeed working to spec when it does show up.

I know you likely don't want to hear this but, your computer is likely not compatible with that RAM if you are having this problem in the first place, that shouldn't happen normally under any circumstances. Your motherboard perhaps is defective or perhaps it is a junky cheap model, or perhaps you got no name brand RAM, who is the manufacturer?

Clearly things are not intended to work that way. It sounds like it is likely the motherboard or BIOS's fault, but stop doing that, you will wear out the slots and have to buy a new motherboard once it stops working altogether. Removing and re-inserting ram is not intended to work like plugging in a flash drive, you will likely break it (further) if you keep doing that.

These are some ideas given how little you wrote but you are not providing anywhere near enough details to properly diagnose your problem. You should at least write something about what kind of computer this is. I mean technical details, model, make, specs, etc not "it's a mac" or "it's a laptop".

Comment: added some details to my question, thank you for your detailed answer, I will check it and get back to u, I know my laptop is dying, I just tried an Adrenalin shot

Comment: you are right, seems like it is dead